# How can I wrote in pinescript that a Moving Average is pointing upwards?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm making my first strategy in pinescript so im learning how to code. Theres a step in my strategy that the moving average need to be pointing upwards.
I was thinking that i could put that the value of the third previous ma candle was below the current value.
The problem is that I don´t know how to do it.
Can someone help with this?

The problem is that I don´t know how to do it.
Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ta.rising()` function to check how many bars your moving average has been rising for.

> `ta.rising(source, length) → series bool`
>
> **RETURNS** 
> true if current `source` is greater than any previous `source` for `length` bars back, false otherwise.
> **ARGUMENTS**
> source (series int/float) Series of values to process. 
> length (series int) Number of bars (length).